# How to set customer image from folder not from database in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have a problem with database size.
In database i have more than 40,000+ customers and each of having image based on the type of customer so, there is may be 15 image only.
each of those customer having that image so, my database size increased and i don't want it.

I want solution to set the image in customer from the filestore or folder so, it takes image from there so, i only need to store 15 images.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachments can be stored in filestore. A possible way is to store the images as attachments, eg have `_set_picture()` and `_get_picture()` methods and a computed binary field that uses them to create/update/delete and retrieve the attachment wherever necessary:

```
picture = fields.Binary(compute='_get_picture', inverse='_set_picture')
```

In a similar fashion, one can also implement an entirely different storage mechanism, which does not rely on Odoo attachments (eg. upload the image to a file server, and store some kind of reference to it in a custom table/field to use by the `get` method).

In your case, you can have an interface to upload images for the specific customer types, and a table customer_type -> image_reference from which `_get_picture` can pick and display the correct image.

*Edit: Perhaps nice approach would be to add a picture field on the customer type table, and then the customer image would just be a `related` field to the customer type.picture*

*Or just attach the picture to the customer type and make the customer picture field fetch that attachment in its compute method*

Comment: Using standard attachments, no additional fields should be required, other than overriding the existing picture/image field.

Comment: i just did as per your suggestion and it's work..
thanks.